# How to align the div horizontally

Tags: css

I am having difficulty aligning the divs in the middle of the page. Hence I have used absolute positioning to place them in the middle.But when I try to do media queries its difficult to place them in the middle. Please any help is appreciated.

```css
nav>ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 114px;
  text-align: center;
  ;
}

nav>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px 45px;
  background: #20639B;
  border-left: 3px solid #34F532;
}

.color2 {
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #20639B;
}
```

```html
<div class="color2">
  <div class="header">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'privacy_policy' %}" target="ifr2"> Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'terms_of_use' %}" target="ifr2"> Terms of Use</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'copyright' %}" target="ifr2">Copyright</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'trademark' %}" target="ifr2">Trademark</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'logos' %}" target="ifr2">Logos</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'pay_transparency' %}" target="ifr2" style="border-right: 3px solid #34F532;">Pay Transparency</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing - you have extra semicolon on `text-align: center;` line. Instead of playing with absolute positioning, take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Just remove `position: absolute` from `nav>ul`, and remove the `float: left` from `nav>ul>li` and replace it with `display: inline-block`.

```css
nav>ul {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px 45px;
  background: #20639B;
  border-left: 3px solid #34F532;
}

.color2 {
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #20639B;
}
```

```html
<div class="color2">
  <div class="header">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'privacy_policy' %}" target="ifr2"> Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'terms_of_use' %}" target="ifr2"> Terms of Use</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'copyright' %}" target="ifr2">Copyright</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'trademark' %}" target="ifr2">Trademark</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'logos' %}" target="ifr2">Logos</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'pay_transparency' %}" target="ifr2" style="border-right: 3px solid #34F532;">Pay Transparency</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No , still it is not centered

Comment: The navbar itself is being centered. I think you're confused by the arbitrarily created background from the `.color2` class. I would remove this whole div and just apply a background color to the navbar itself, rather than creating a div that isn't really doing anything.

Comment: I've edited the code snippet if you want to keep the `div` there. Add `padding-top: 10px` to `nav>ul` to align it with the `div`. Again though, a better option is to just color the `nav` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this js fiddle

https://jsbin.com/geqovukozo/edit?css,output

[image]

```
nav{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  width:100%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
nav>ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size:0;
}

nav>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px 45px;
  background: #20639B;
  border-left: 3px solid #34F532;
}

.color2 {
  border-bottom: 45px solid #20639B;
}
```

Use positions with transform property in this case. and instead of float:left; use display:inline-block;

Comment: I need to use position to align it vertically . text aling center and display inline block didnt work for me

Comment: add this lines  nav{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  width:100%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

updated the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can be one way to go. Here a quick JS Fiddle that shows you how you can achieve what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/58u76mrn/13/

```
 nav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100vw;
 }

 nav a {
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 10px 45px 10px 45px;
   background: #20639B;
   border-left: 3px solid #34F532;
 }

 .color2 {
   height: 0px;
 }
```